# dispose or use the keyword "using"

Tags: c#, odbc

Do I really need to use `comm.Dispose()` and `conn.Dispose()` or directly used the `using`?

```
using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection())
{
    conn.Open();
    OdbcCommand comm = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn);
    OdbcDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader();

    while (dr.Read())
    {
      //codes here...
    }

    conn.Close();
    dr.Close();
    comm.Dispose();
    conn.Dispose();
}
```

If that is the case, I'm thinking to do this.

Snippet:

```
using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection())
{
    conn.Open();
    using(OdbcCommand comm = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn))
    {
        using(OdbcDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                //codes here...
            }
        }
        dr.Close();

    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Would this be more appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can just use `using` - it calls `Dispose` for you.

You can also omit the `Close`, because `Dispose` will call that for you.

```
using (OdbcConnection conn = new OdbcConnection())
{
    conn.Open();
    using(OdbcCommand comm = new OdbcCommand(sql, conn))        
    using(OdbcDataReader dr = comm.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (dr.Read())
        {
            //codes here...
        }
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The second example is appropriate (except for `dr` not being in scope when `Close` is called on it - also `Dispose` often calls `Close` for these types of things) as

```
using(IDisposable foo = ...)
{
    //Do stuff using foo
}
```

is equivalent to

```
IDisposable foo = ...;

try
{
    //Do stuff using foo
}
finally
{
    foo.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: I notice that, it should be inside the `using`